# Installing rpy2 on Mac OSX 10.8.5

Tags: python-2.7, pip, osx-mountain-lion, rpy2

I'm trying to install rpy2 on Mac Mountain Lion (10.8.5) with pip:

```
sudo pip install rpy2
```

and get the following error message:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

My python version is 2.7.2, R version is 3.2.1.

In some posts I've read that I need to install Xcode and command line tools to solve the problem, but I had both already installed (Xcode 5.1.1).

(The following is added after a suggestion by Eric Appelt, to whom I'm very thankful:)

I have also tried to set the ARCHFLAGS in order to disable the error message:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install rpy2
```

but now I got the following error message:

```
clang: warning: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:104:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                          ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                          ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
      SEXP res = rpy_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
           ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:125:
./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:738:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
  PyObject *copy = Py_True;
            ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:129:
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:267:30: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'R_len_t' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    R_len_t slice_len = ihigh-ilow;
            ~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~^~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:522:30: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'R_len_t' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    R_len_t slice_len = ihigh-ilow;
            ~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~^~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:390:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
  default:
  ^~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:416:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
  if (consolecallback == NULL) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:382:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
  void *consolecallback;
                       ^
                        = NULL
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:625:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  int l=strlen(input_str);
      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:832:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  int l=strlen(path_str);
      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1338:28: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'const Py_ssize_t' (aka 'const long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  status = Rf_initialize_R(n_args, options);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1730:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  nparams = PySequence_Length(params);
          ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:1065:27: note: expanded from macro 'PySequence_Length'
#define PySequence_Length PySequence_Size
                          ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:129:
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2174:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
^
14 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future build/temp.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -lpcre -llzma -licucore -lm -liconv -o build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R
ld: library not found for -llzma
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Any help will be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: Try `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future sudo pip install rpy2` as a workaround.

Comment: Sorry - the sudo should come first - `sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install rpy2`

Comment: Hi Eric, many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it's not working either. I'm getting the same error although now preceded by several other error messages. I've added them in my main message above for convenience. Any ideas of what may be going on there? Thanks!